# Visual Studio External Symbol Error while file is present

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to compile [minidump_file_writer_unittests](https://github.com/wasimbhai/break_pad/tree/master/breakpad/src/client) located here to compile on my Windows machine. You can clone the repository to download the solution. The code previously was only compiled for Linux so there are some problems. Currently, I am facing Unresolved External Symbol error. I understand that this error is because my code can't find the relevant source files.

Concretely, the basic problem is that [minidump_file_writer.cc](https://github.com/wasimbhai/break_pad/blob/master/breakpad/src/client/minidump_file_writer.cc) fails to locate the function `UTF32ToUTF16Char(*str, out)` on line 122 and `UTF8ToUTF16Char` on line 151. This function is present in [`..\common\string_conversion.h`](https://github.com/wasimbhai/break_pad/blob/master/breakpad/src/common/string_conversion.h) and the source file for this header file is in the same directory. I have included the source in the project and yet it fails to detect the problem.

Can you please see where exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include file `convert_UTF.c` to your "minidump_file_writer_unittest" project. It compiles after that.

Comment: Mikhail, I included the `convert_UTF.cc` but it still doesn't compile. Did you check it?

Comment: I assume from your reply to the other thread that you fixed the problem?

Comment: However, I already did a pull-request which fixes your bug. I also cleaned up your repo a bit. You shouldn't include build-specific files in a git repo. Please, accept it.