# Visual Studio External Dependencies Symbol error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to compile a program where the header files are located in External Dependencies folder inside VS Solution. Now for these header files, I have included source files, and when I right click `go to definition` at each function in header files, it jumps to the function definition in the source file. But when I compile the code, it gives me `unresolved external symbol error.` Why is this the case?

Comment: So (looking at the link to the earlier question) have you included string_conversion.cc in your project?

Comment: Thanks John a ton. It successfully compiled. I stand grateful.

Comment: @john how did you come to know that I had to include string_conversion.cc in my project along with convert_UTF.c? What did I miss?

Comment: I just looked for the source file that contained function referenced in the linker error. Since the header file was string_common.h it wasn't too hard to guess what the source file was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Go to definition" feature of IntelliSence have nothing to do with compiler (or linker) itself. You need to make sure that source files are compiled and linked to your program. Post more details to get more detailed answer.

Comment: Mikhail, thanks for the comment. Here [1] is a more detailed version of question that I posted last night. Please let me know if there is anything else that I need to clear. [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035602/visual-studio-external-symbol-error-while-file-is-present

Comment: I answered the linked question.

Comment: How exactly did you come to know that convert_UTF.c should have been included? What did I miss? I will be grateful for a response.

Comment: Because that was exactly what linker said. He couldn't find `ConvertUTF8toUTF16`, which is called from `google_breakpad::UTF8ToUTF16Char`. I just searched files for `ConvertUTF8toUTF16` and found it in `convert_UTF.c`.